# Azure Alerts - Create standard web test with API WITHOUT http status code check?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I'm setting up an [Azure Alert Rule for a Webtest with Terraform and ARM template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70063660/creating-an-azure-alert-rule-for-a-webtest-with-terraform-or-arm-template). Works fine.

Some of the URLs that I need to check might return "error" (http status code >= 400). When I manually modify or setup the alert, I'd disable "HTTP response" in "Success criteria".

How would I do that in an ARM template? I exported two tests in portal and diff'd them. There's no difference. See https://gist.github.com/alexs77/fc61992f84cf2d3ca80bda54cb2717cb for details.

According to [Microsoft.Insights webtests 2018-05-01-preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/2018-05-01-preview/webtests?tabs=json) I would have expected, that setting `IgnoreHttpsStatusCode` would do just that. But no matter if I set it to `true` or `false`, the created web test has "HTTP response" enabled.

Well?!?

How do you create a web test with HTTP resonse disabled?

[image: http response section in webtest configuration]

Comment: Hello @alexanderSkwar, if you don't provide parameter `testhttpcode` and `expectedhttpstatuscode` . it won't be set .. as if you would have observed  when you pass httpstatuscode 404 , it enables http response and selects response code equals and set it to 404

Comment: let me try it out and get back here

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments , I tested using the same criteria by not providing `httpstatuscode` in `ExpectedHttpStatusCode` and setting it to **null** . I also set the `IgnoreHttpsStatusCode` as true just to be on safer side.

```
"ValidationRules": {
            "ExpectedHttpStatusCode": null,
            "IgnoreHttpsStatusCode": true,
            "ContentValidation": null,
            "SSLCheck": true,
            "SSLCertRemainingLifetimeCheck": "[parameters('certRemainingLifetimeCheck')]"
          }
```

But the above only sets the `HTTP response:`  as null . It doesn't disable the ***HTTP response***. Even if you are not providing `ExpectedHttpStatusCode` and `IgnoreHttpsStatusCode` , then also it enables **Http Response** and sets it to `null` .

```
      "ValidationRules": {
        "ContentValidation": null,
        "SSLCheck": true,
        "SSLCertRemainingLifetimeCheck": "[parameters('certRemainingLifetimeCheck')]"
      }
```

Setting some HTTP code in the response and adding the `IgnoreHttpsStatusCode` as true will ignore the same http code that you have provided in the test runs as mentioned in the **[Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/2018-05-01-preview/webtests?tabs=json#webtestpropertiesvalidationrules)** you have referred to.

[image]

[image]

**Final conclusion will be it is not possible to disable the HTTP response in success criteria using ARM Template but it can be set to Null even if its enabled.**

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else comes across this. There's apparently a typo in the spec.

It should be

```json
"ValidationRules": {
  "ExpectedHttpStatusCode": 0,
  "IgnoreHttpStatusCode": true,
  "SSLCheck": true,
  "SSLCertRemainingLifetimeCheck": 30
}
```

Thanks to [this MS Learn forum post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1075124/index.html)